# Why is memory access in the lowest address space (non-null though) reported as NullReferenceException by .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

This causes an `AccessViolationException` to be thrown:

```
using System;

namespace TestApplication
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static unsafe void Main()
        {
            ulong* addr = (ulong*)Int64.MaxValue;
            ulong val = *addr;
        }
    }
}
```

This causes a `NullReferenceException` to be thrown:

```
using System;

namespace TestApplication
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static unsafe void Main()
        {
            ulong* addr = (ulong*)0x000000000000FF;
            ulong val = *addr;
        }
    }
}
```

They're both invalid pointers and both violate memory access rules.
Why the NullReferenceException?

Comment: It's not clear what programming problem this is going to solve. This sounds like just idle curiosity.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you running 64 bit or 32 bit? Perhaps that makes a difference?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I mentioned in a comment to another answer that it was 64-bit and that changing to uint instead of ulong didn't fix it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is caused by a Windows design decision made many years ago.  The bottom 64 kilobytes of the address space is reserved.  An access to any address in that range is reported with a null reference exception instead of the underlying access violation.  This was a wise choice, a null pointer can produce reads or writes at addresses that are not actually zero.  Reading a field of a C++ class object for example, it has an offset from the start of the object.  If the object pointer is null then the code will bomb from reading at an address that's larger than 0.

C# doesn't have quite the same problem, the language guarantees that a null reference is caught before you can call an instance method of a class.  This is however language specific, it is not a CLR feature.  You can write managed code in C++/CLI and generate non-zero null pointer dereferences.  Calling a method on a nullptr object works.  That method will merrily execute.  And call other instance methods.  Until it tries to access an instance variable or call a virtual method, which requires dereferencing *this*, kaboom then.

The C# guarantee is very nice, it makes diagnosing null reference problems much easier since they are generated at the call site and don't bomb somewhere inside a nested method.  And it is fundamentally safer, the instance variable might not trigger an exception on extremely large objects when its offset is larger than 64K.  Pretty hard to do in managed code btw, unlike C++.  But doesn't come for free, explained in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/05/17/133570.aspx).

Comment: Isn't it more of a legacy PC issue than anything else?

Comment: @Ritch - No, that's why I gave the example of C++/CLI, a thoroughly modern language.

Comment: So if I have an object with more than 64 kilobytes of fields and then try to access a specific field from an instance of that object when it is assigned null, it won't throw a `NullReferenceException` because the field offset will be more than 65535 and thus compute into an address beyond that?

Comment: @JNZ - right.  Worse, there are considerable odds that you get no exception at all because memory happens to be mapped at that address.  Which happened when I tried it.

Comment: @HansPassant I noticed that as well when I played around with it, address 65536 seemed to be mapped at least 4 bytes out to zeroes and the code executed fine. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Hans: So can one conclude that `someReferenceTypeExpression.SomeField = someValue;` is a fundamentally unsafe expression, even in C#, for a massive object?

Comment: Yes, programmers that write classes with more than 4096 public fields write fundamentally broken code.  But everybody already knows that :)

Comment: @Ani: From my testing, accesses to a field with an offset beyond 64K was still trapped.  Since the JIT knows field offsets, it wouldn't be hard for it to generate an explicit null check when accessing fields at offsets beyond 64K, and omit it for fields with smaller offsets.

Answer (score 17):

A null reference exception and an access violation exception are both raised by the CPU as an access violation. The CLR then has to guess whether the access violation should be specialized to a null reference exception or left as the more general access violation.

It is evident from your results that the CLR infers that access violations at addresses very close to 0 are caused by a null reference. Because they were almost certainly generated by a null reference plus field offset. Your use of unsafe code fools this heuristic.

Comment: With that in mind it would mean that any large enough class would cause an AccessViolationException erroneously when trying to access it while it is assigned null, which it should not do.

Comment: In that case, the CLR will probably do [an explicit dereference at offset 0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/16/4407029.aspx) before accessing the field, to avoid the false negative.

Comment: More precisely this heuristic comes from the fact that Windows will never naturally give you memory below 64KB (you can force it via NtAllocateVirtualMemory - although you can't even do that on Windows8 except in NTVDM - but I digress). Consequently any managed object causing an AV is a null-dereference of an object less than 64KB in size. To avoid accidentally reporting objects > 64KB as an AccessViolation rather than a NullDereference, the CLR will automatically "touch" the first byte of any >64KB object before referencing a field more than 64KB from the start

Comment: @RaymondChen The CLR always knows the true offset of a field when the JIT reaches a `ldfld` or `stfld` instruction. If the field offset is greater than the size of the area where a CPU access violation results in a `NullReferenceException` it will emit one of the `cmp` instructions on the object itself to make sure you really do see the proper exception. The explicit `cmp` can be (and is) omitted for fields at lower offsets.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a semantics issue.

Your first example is trying to dereference a pointer whose content is the **address** Int64.MaxValue, not a pointer to a variable that has a **value** of Int64.MaxValue.

Looks like you're trying to read the value stored at the address Int64.MaxValue, which is, apparently not in the range that's owned by your process.

Do you mean something like this?

```
        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ulong val = 1;// some variable space to store an integer
            ulong* addr = &val;
            ulong read = *addr;

            Console.WriteLine("Val at {0} = {1}", (ulong)addr, read);

#if DEBUG 
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
            Console.ReadLine();
#endif
        }
```

Comment: Nope, just playing around and noticed the inconsistency between the exceptions being thrown. Kind of curious as to why there's a difference. I understand the addresses are totally invalid for the process.

Comment: @JNZ I'm getting NullReferenceException for both of them. Hmmm.

Answer (score 2):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception.aspx

> Version Information
>
> This exception is new in the .NET Framework version 2.0. In earlier
>   versions of the .NET Framework, an access violation in unmanaged code
>   or unsafe managed code is represented by a NullReferenceException in
>   managed code. A NullReferenceException is also thrown when a null
>   reference is dereferenced in verifiable managed code, an occurrence
>   that does not involve data corruption, and there is no way to
>   distinguish between the two situations in versions 1.0 or 1.1.
>
> Administrators can allow selected applications to revert to the
>   behavior of the .NET Framework version 1.1. Place the following line
>   in the  Element section of the configuration file for the
>   application:
>
> other `<legacyNullReferenceExceptionPolicy enabled = "1"/>`

Comment: So since when is 0x000000000000FF the same as null?

Comment: It adds no new information and I apologize but I do not see your point.