# Why does this unsafe code throw a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, unsafe

I was playing with unsafe code for a problem on [Code Golf,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4399/2718) and I found something I can't explain. This code:

```
unsafe
{
    int i = *(int*)0;
}
```

Crashes with an access violation (Segfault), but this code:

```
unsafe
{
    *(int*)0=0;
}
```

Throws a NullReferenceException. It appears to me that the first is performing a read and the second is performing a write. An exception tells me that something, somewhere in the CLR is intercepting the write and stopping it before the OS kills the process. Why does this happen on the write, but not on the read? It does segfault on a write if I make the pointer value sufficiently large. Does that mean there is a block of memory that the CLR knows is reserved and will not even attempt to write to? Why then, does it allow me to try and read from that block? Am I completely misunderstanding something here?

#### Edit:

Interestingly enough: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteInt32(IntPtr.Zero, 0);` Gives me an access violation, not a NullReference.

Comment: On my machine both throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Speculation: the second one throws a NullReferenceException because the compiler was able to figure out that this is what it will always do, and it replaced the exception with a throw statement.

Comment: @MikeNakis: I assure you that the compiler is not that sophisticated.

Comment: Both snippets of code cause an unmanaged AccessViolation exception (exception code 0xc0000005) which then gets translated by the .NET exception processing code to NullReferenceException since the access happened in the lower 64KB of the virtual memory address space.  Hard to guess why you don't get NRE on the 1st snippet.  You'll get an AVE with `*(int*)-1`. More about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7940659/17034

Comment: @EricLippert Oh, OK. I guess I can now consider myself as having that on good authority.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first exception makes sense, of course - you're trying to read from memory address 0. The second one's a little more interesting. :P In C++, there is a macro/constant called NULL which has a value of 0. It is used for pointer addresses that are invalid - much like the null value in C# for reference types. Since C# references are pointers internally, a NullReferenceException occurs when you try to read/write from that address - the address NULL or 0; in fact, the addresses from 0 to 64K are invalid in all processes (in Windows) so as to catch programer mistakes. The exact exception or error may vary slightly by computer hardware or version of Windows/.NET Framework, but you should get an error with both code snippets.

As for the segfault when reading/writing to random addresses, that is due to the OS's isolation of each process. You can't fiddle around with other processes' code or data - at least not legitimately.

Comment: I thought that too, but many values give the NullReferenceException, not just zero. I get it on values up to 100k or so. After that, a few values execute without error (I assume they are in my program's memory space, but I'm not sure), and others give AccessViolationExceptions.

Comment: In order to catch programmer mistakes early in the development cycle, the virtual addresses from 0 to 64K  are invalid in all processes.

I'd also assume the valid addresses are within your process's reserved memory.

Comment: That makes sense `*(int*)65536 = 0` is the first value to run successfully.

Comment: @CMP: Dereferencing 0x00000004, say, is also a null reference exception because the most likely situation in which dereferencing 4 arises is something like `int* x = &intArray[1]; int y = *x;`. If the int array is null then its 0 element will be at 0 and its 1 element will be at 4. Dereferencing 4 is usually because you got there via a null.

Comment: "As for the segfault when reading/writing to random addresses, that is due to the OS's isolation of each process. You can't fiddle around with other processes' code or data - at least not legitimately." Doesn't make much sense. All user mode addresses you reach with normal reads/writes are in your own process. Each process has its own virtual memory. To reach the memory of other processes you need `Read/WriteProcessMemory`.